# Flutter - show loader on upcoming message left side in chat app. shows the loader until a response is received

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _chatHistory.length,
              shrinkWrap: false,
              controller: _scrollController,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final isSender = _chatHistory[index]["isSender"];
                final messageText = _chatHistory[index]["message"];
                final messageOwner =
                    isSender ? MessageOwner.myself : MessageOwner.other;
                return MessageBubble(
                  message: Message(owner: messageOwner, text: messageText),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 14, right: 14, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                    child: (index < _chatHistory.length - 1 && isLoading)
                        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                              Colors.red,
                            ),
                          )
                        : Text(
                            _chatHistory[index]["message"],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              color: isSender ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: like Instagram chat, when user is type that time showing "typing" animation. that kind of something i want.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

First off, your backend needs to be capable of handling real-time events. This means it should recognize when a user starts or stops typing and broadcast this status. Generally applications achieve this by using web-sockets to emit and listen to the events. If you're using Firebase, for instance, this would involve setting a value in your database that represents the typing status of a user.

## The Firebase Approach

### Step 1: Listening to Typing Events

In Flutter, you'd use a `StreamController` to manage this real-time data. You can set up a listener that watches for changes in the typing status.

```
StreamController<bool> _typingController = StreamController<bool>();

void listenToTypingEvents(String chatRoomId) {
  FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref('chatrooms/$chatRoomId/typingStatus')
  .onValue
  .listen((event) {
    final isTyping = event.snapshot.value ?? false;
    _typingController.add(isTyping);
  });
}
```

This code snippet listens to changes in the `typingStatus` and updates our `_typingController` with the current typing state.

### Step 2: Updating the UI

To reflect the typing status in your app's UI, you can use a `StreamBuilder` that listens to `_typingController`. Whenever the status changes, the UI updates accordingly.

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
  stream: _typingController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!) {
     return Text("User is typing...");
    }
  return SizedBox.shrink(); // Nothing to show when no one's typing.
 },
)
```

### Step 3: Sending Typing Notifications

Whenever a user starts or stops typing, you'll need to notify your backend.

```
void updateUserTypingStatus(String chatRoomId, bool isTyping) {
  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('chatrooms/$chatRoomId').update({
    "typingStatus": isTyping
  });
}
```

Remember to call this method with true when typing begins and false when it ends. It's also a good idea to debounce these updates to prevent overwhelming your backend with too many requests.

And **voila!** There you have it! Adjustments might be needed based on your exact requirements and backend setup, but this should give you a solid foundation.